# ASP.NET MVC 3 - How to handle errors in Global.asax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling, global-asax

What is best practice for handling errors that occur in Global.asax (for example in SessionStart)?

In my case I need to handle exceptions that are thrown from a helper class that handles queries against Active Directory.

How do I proceed when I catch an error to inform the user of, for instance, that the AD server cannot be reached?

Comment: What kind of errors? For what event handler?

Comment: I improved the question a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a SessionStart method and you're doing work in it, put a try catch in there.  If you're talking about errors from your other controllers and other actions, the best way in my opinion is to create a `BaseController` and override the `OnException` method.  Do all your error handling in there (redirect to an error view, log, etc.).  Now, when you make a controller, just inherit from `BaseController`.  See more here:

http://blog.dantup.com/2009/04/aspnet-mvc-handleerror-attribute-custom.html

Comment: Yeah but if I catch some exception in the SessionStart method, how do I proceed from there? Can I redirect to my error controller?

Comment: No, that's outside of a request, so you don't have anything to redirect - SessionStart is before any action is invoked.